# IOS app switching animation "A" with animation "B" in the same place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have 2 animations. The initial one when the app loads, and a second one which will be the one that stays put through the remainder of the user experience.

Here is what i want to do in the nutshell

1) animation "A" which loads when the app loads.
2) then i want to hide animationa "A" and replace it with animation "B" on the same coordinates
3) have animation "B" play any other time or on an interval of 30 seconds or 45

Animation A

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 
                      delay:2.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{[buhoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(91, 185, 130, 130)];}completion:nil];
```

Animation B

```
animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_0.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_4.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_3.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_2.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_1.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Buho128x128_0.png"], nil];
[animation setAnimationRepeatCount:-1];
animation.animationDuration = 1;
[animation startAnimating];
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting the code for Animation B into the completition block of Animation A:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 
                  delay:2.0 
                options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
             animations:^{[buhoButton setFrame:CGRectMake(91, 185, 130, 130)];}
             completion:^(BOOL finished){/*Animation B code here*/;}
];
```

Comment: that did it for starting animation B when A finished. now, I am faced with how to hide animation A once in done so just animation B stays behind.

Comment: you want to hide the button when Animation A is completed? If so, set buhoButton.hidden = YES; on the completion block.

Comment: well, now i am running into another problem. is is posible to make and animation clikable? i manage to get all the animation a and b aling and one starting after the other one finished but now how can I make animation.animationImages clickable. Btw, thanks for all your help, I have learn plenty with this questions. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want control over when animation B triggers you could use a CABAsicAnimation with removedOnCompletion = YES for animation A (placed in your viewDidLoad) and removedOnCompletion = NO for animation B (placed where your tiggering event is handled).

Comment: do you have an example or some snip to see how i would take this route?

Comment: Here is an example from Apple's MoveMe sample code:

CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];   
transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
transformAnimation.duration = animationDuration;